# Why the Enter key in a Mac keyboard is mapped to Level?

Tags: keyboard, mac

Just installing Ubuntu for the first time, glad to ditch Win 7. I have a KVM switch and also a Mac, hence I'm using a Mac keyboard (the full size alu one)

Main problem is the Enter key on the keypad doesn't work. I checked the keyboard layout (set to 'English UK Macintosh')... inspecting the layout the Enter key is mapped to something called 'Level' - WTF is 'Level'?

Everything else about the keyboard works great ie the £ $ # @ " are all perfect, volume control works as expected... why this weird key mapping on the Enter key?

More importantly... how do I change it to work *as an Enter key* ?

Comment: ok, I found that this will fix it temporarily: `sudo /usr/bin/xmodmap -e 'keycode 104 = KP_Enter'` but after I logout and login the old mapping is back. Anyone know how to make this permanent?  More to the point, could some Ubuntu dev just fix the source keyboard mapping...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok the following seems to have fixed it permanently for me:

```
> /usr/bin/xmodmap -e 'keycode 104 = KP_Enter'
> xmodmap -pke > ~/.Xmodmap
```

I shouldn't have to do this, someone please fix the *English (UK, Macintosh)* keyboard layout (for full-size aluminium Mac keyboard) that comes with Ubuntu 12 and save others this annoyance...

Comment: If you want some developer to fix the bug, you will need to open a bug report, see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Comment: I'm wondering if `KP_Enter` is actually what you want--`Return` may be a more useful key code; I recently have had a problem with the fact that my enter key maps to `KP_Enter` when numlock is on and `Return` when numlock is off, and `KP_Enter` doesn't work in all situations...

Comment: `Enter` and `Return` have different meanings for some programs (eg Sublime Text 2) so I particularly needed an Enter key